# VMWare Unrecoverable Error

Tags: vmware

I shut my VM down in a hurry earlier today - bad move it seems.

Now, when I try to boot it, it comes up with an unrecoverable error.  The log file says something about 'disk error while paging'.  Any ideas?  Any way out?

It's a Windows 7 Host and a Ubuntu Guest.  (I don't think this makes any difference though...)

UPDATE:

- I ran a chkdsk /r on the host but it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

Per this article, http://eng-mah.blogspot.com/2011/04/vmware-virtual-machine-cannot-resume.html, I deleted the vmem file and the machine restored fine!